# Symfony2 applicaiton's with common code

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, code-organization

I've have sf2 based **api and admin apps**, *it's separated*. But it uses one database. Now api works with database through doctrine entities and admin project is using native sql calls. And it's very annoying.

**So my decision is to make common code reachable for 2 application. Mostly it will be doctrine entities.**

Maybe someone have made something like that and have a good mechanizm. **Ideas are welcome too.**

For now I have only one idea, putt the entities in some other dir(**synced with 3d repository**) and config both projects to use it. 
*But I can't get rid of thoughts that it can be made in simpler way.*

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. Could you clarify what exactly the question is? it sounds like you've already decided.

Comment: Looking for the best(or just good) way to have common entities for both projects

Comment: What i did in the same situation was making both applications the same
And then divided then by Bundles, so you would have CommonBundle
SiteBundle and AdminBundle this way you can do what you want
if you really want to make your entities available in another applications you should try thiking on restful services they can provide you with what you need

Comment: api = restful, and I think using simmilar bundles not a good idea, because hard to maintain such code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common and convenient way to share code between several applications is using Composer packages:

- Extract the code of entities in a separate library and create a Composer package (if you want to make it private, create a private repository with Satis or Toran Proxy)
- Install this new package in your admin and api apps.

To be able to edit and commit code for your new private library directly in the `vendor/` directory of your apps, use the `--prefer-source` flag when you run `composer install` or `update`.

But here, you should ask yourself if it really make sense to have separate apps and repositories for the API and admin.